# How do I diagnose steps in a trigger on MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, toad, diagnostics

I have two tables:

- *source* table
- *result* table

I have an **after update trigger** on my *source* table which updates some records in *result* table. the problem is, my trigger is not updating *result* table and I would like to diagnose my trigger execution.

I tried putting `select` statements to see variable values but selects are not allowed in a trigger. I would like to use something similar to `PRINT` in Microsoft SQL Management Studio that would output some values in GUI but this command doesn't seem to exist on MySQL or Toad tool that I'm using.

**How am I suppose to diagnose my trigger then?** How do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a log table.

```
CREATE TABLE log (t datetime, comment varchar(255));
```

In your trigger you can insert the log.

```
INSERT INTO log 
SELECT now(), concat('debug comment ', @your_variable);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I did just that about an hour ago... Does help a lot, but it's more of a workaround.